# Change property on object on event without codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to change Visibility on a textbox when the event "DropDownClosed" on a combobox occurs. The thing is, I can't use codebehind (and thereby eventtrigers I think?) because I am trying to follow the Model-View-Viewmodel design.

An example of what I am looking for:

```
<Grid>
<ComboBox x:Name="Combobox">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="true"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="false"/>
</ComboBox>
<TextBlock Text="Some text" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>

            // Code that makes textbox visibility become "collapsed" when Combobox event "DropDownClosed" occurs.

        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't agree that you can't use codebehind. may be because you are following MVVM design pattern. MVVM doesn't enforce such rules. Codebehind has its own pace & ViewModels have their own pace. Though i agree that for binding, you stick with viewmodel. What you'll do is create ICommand in viewmodel, set viewmodel in your zammel, bind Command with Combobox *DropDownClosed* event. Your Command in ViewModel will update property(which should be bound with the *Visibility* property of your textbox). Binding engine will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple working example based on the code fragment you posted.  I'll go over it step by step.

XAML (I'm using a StackPanel for ease of use.)

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Combobox"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding Choice, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="true"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="false"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

First we declare a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) resource. This is a built-in class that does exactly what you need, it converts a bool value to a Visibility value

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Next, we bind the ComboBox to a property of the ViewModel called Choice. Note that I am binding the SelectedIndex property

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Combobox"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Choice, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <ComboBoxItem Content="true"/>
     <ComboBoxItem Content="false"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Finally, I'm binding the Visibility property of the TextBlock to a boolean property of the ViewModel called Visible, this binding is using the BooleanToVisibilty property we declared as a resource

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
           Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
</TextBlock>
```

I also removed the TextBlock style as it was not needed. The Visibility can be set on the TextBlock directly.

Now for the ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int choice = 0;
    public int Choice
    {
        get { return choice; }
        set
        {
            if (value != choice)
            {
                choice = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, 
                                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Choice"));
                }
                Visible = choice == 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool visible = true;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return visible; }
        set
        {
            if (value != visible)
            {
                visible = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, 
                                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visible"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I noted earlier the Choice property is declared as an int, and is being bound in the XAML to the SelectedIndex property, which is also an int. I did this for the sake of simplicity as I didn't want to introduce another Converter to translate your "true" and "false" strings into a true/false boolean value. I do not consider this an ideal design, but it serves it's purpose.

```
  Visible = choice == 0;
```

This line sets the boolean Visible property whenever Choice is changed. It sets it to true if index == 0 (which is the "true" string of your ComboBox) and sets it to false otherwise. This in turn causes the Visible property to raise a notification, and the BoolToVisibility converter converts that bool to Visibility.Visible when true or Visibility.Collapsed when false.

Answer (score 0):

Will the combo items be a fixed list, e.g. the true and false at the moment?

if so you can bind the selected value of your combo to a property on your view model and then use a converter to convert the visibility of your textblock

Comment: What do you mean with a fixed list? Sorry, very noob.

Comment: are you loading the values from a database and can they be changed elsewhere. At the moment you just have 2 items true & false hard coded in your xaml

Comment: The True/false items are not coming from a database, but they are going to one (converted from string to bool and assigned to a property), when item is chosen and a button is pushed. So by that definition I guess they are fixed yeah. I will try your fix, see how it goes. Thanks :)